# Javascript local scopes and using objects - best practice?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I am currently working on large projects that make use of lots of javascript files.
I then start learning of using local scopes and using objects.

What I do not really understand is how to call them into you local scope?
E.g if I create an object in an local scope in file-a, how can I use them as in a function in the document.ready scope file-b?

I get that you can find this online, but I get demotivation by the high amount of javascript on the internet and can't really find good examples or material. Any help?

Comment: The whole point of scoping is that other files *can't* access your variables. You need to either condense your code into one file or expose global variables appropriately.

Comment: No research done on OPS part to find an answer . As Admitted by the post

Comment: Try looking into the [ES6 module pattern](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/Brief-Overview-of-ES6-Module-syntax).

Comment: Well, why would u use different scopes on the same page then? Just so you don't mess up other code running that you are badly aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure,but I think you might be referring to the use of namespaces within JavaScript as a way to avoid adding all your functions to the main window object.

**The Ugly Way**

Let's assume you have 3 functions related to cats:

```
Function AddCat(cat) {

}

Function DeleteCat(catId) {

}

Function BreedCat(cat,cat) {

}
```

The way these items are coded, they are globally available. Not only does that clutter up your window object, it's hard to share data between these functions in a discreet way.

As long as this js file is loaded, any function in your app can call these functions just by calling `AddCat()`

**Cleaner**

To solve that problem, we could create a Cats object that acts as a "namespace" here:

```
Cats = {

    AddCat: function(cat) {

    },

    DeleteCat: function(catId) {

    },

    BreedCat: function(cat,cat) {

    }

}
```

Now, you've only added ONE object to the windows class: Cats. In addition, other methods in your web app can call any of those 3 items by calling `Cats.AddCat()` for example.

This lets you **encapsulate** all of the Cat data in your entire system within a single "namespace, so it's easier to read.

This can get a lot more detailed. By encapsulating items like this, you can start to hide variables that all your cat routines require from the rest of your code.

There is an excellent set of resources on this type of namespacing (including tons of detail) [here](https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/) and [here](https://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) with links that lead you deeper.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you for your time to explain this to me :D

Comment: No worries. I love this stuff!  Be sure to check those link. Both those guys are really smart and have saved me hours of refactoring.